# Need help randomising xpath extractor value

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am currently doing a foundation course in a jmeter course as a self study, few days ago I received a good help on this site in terms of using xpath expression rather than regular expressions which I am grateful for. However I only needed to input the value 0 in the "Match No" in order to randomize the selection.

Is there a way to make the XPath expression match several nodes? I have found some good stuff online but I am unable to understand how to implement this for my xpath expression?

```
${__Random(1,${refName_matchNr},n)}
```

Should `refName` be my xpath expression?

Comment: Yes, you can select multiple nodes with XPath as seen in the answer to your previous question. What do you want to achieve? Please provide code/markup and where do you encounter this. In what way do you want to randomize?

Comment: well, for example if i want my script to run for 3 iterations I would want to select a different value for each iteration. using the css/jQuery Iam getting no values?                              css/jQuery expression: select[name=fromPort] > option                                 html of the options                                           <SELECT NAME="fromPort">
<OPTION VALUE="Acapulco">Acapulco
<OPTION VALUE="Frankfurt">Frankfurt
<OPTION VALUE="London">London......

Answer (score 0):

XPath extractor stores all matching elements into variables. I.e. if your variable is called `test` and matches several values JMeter will save them as follows:

```
test_1
test_2
test_3
....
```

There will be also `test_matchNr` variable holding all possible matches.

If you want to combine 2 variables you need to use [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function.

- ${A1} - works OK
- ${A${N}} - does not work (nested variable reference)
- ${__V(A${N})} - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for details on how to deal with multiple matches.